# Ignore case in IF comparision

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, case-sensitive, ignore-case

Is there an easy way to do this comparision with ignorecase ON?

```
If file.Extension = ".Lnk" Then MsgBox(file.Extension)
```

What i'm trying to do is to get all the ".lnk" or ".LNK" or ".lNk" or " ".Lnk" etc...

I know this is possibly with RegEx but... there's an easy way for that example?

Thankyou for read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the extension to lowercase using ToLower and then compare

```
If file.Extension.ToLower = ".lnk" Then MsgBox(file.Extension)
```

And forget Regex for this. It's really overkill and inappropriate

Comment: No, it returns a copy of the string `file.Extension` converted to lowercase, so, in the subsequent comparison you could always check with a fixed lower case string constant.

Answer (score 5):

Use `String.Equals` for string comparisons. To ignore case use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

```
If String.Equals("AAA", "aaa", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then

    'more code

End If
```

[MSDN: String.Equals Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN: Specifying String Comparisons Explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121(v=vs.110).aspx#specifying_string_comparisons_explicitly)

Answer (score 2):

use this for ignore case compare

```
If String.Compare(file.Extension, ".lnk", True) = 0 Then MsgBox(file.Extension)
```

change true to false for case sensitive compare

Comment: I think String.Equals would be better and wouldn't require the '= 0' part and would read better.

Comment: returns 
[< 0 - string 1 is less than string 2] 
[> 0 - string 1 is gr than string 2] 
[= 0 - both are equal]

Answer (score 0):

Module Test

```
Sub Main()
    Dim userString As String = Nothing
    Dim finalString As String = "Jacob"

    Console.WriteLine("Enter username")
    userString = Console.ReadLine()

    If String.Compare(finalString, userString, True) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Access Granted")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Access Denied")
    End If


    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

End Module